# How does Javascript match the parameters in a callback function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I just started to learn JavaScript, and callback functions seem hard to understand. One question I have is how javascript matches the parameters in a callback function? for example in the following forEach loop:

```js
    var friends = ['Mike', 'Stacy', 'Andy', 'Rick'];    
    friends.forEach(function(eachName, index){
          console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName);
        });
```

Is it by default that the forEach function will pass index to the second parameter and entry to the first parameter in the callback function?

In order to master callback functions, do I need to check the API (in this case, forEach) every time I use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do the parameters in a javascript callback function come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624634/where-do-the-parameters-in-a-javascript-callback-function-come-from)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it by default that the forEach function will pass index to the second parameter and entry to the first parameter in the callback function?

Yes; [this is part of the specification](https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18). In fact, it also passes the array being iterated as the third argument.

> Call the [[Call]] internal method of callbackfn with T as the this value **and argument list containing [the value], [the index], and [the object]**.

(Emphasis mine.)

> In order to master callback functions, do I need to check the API (in this case, forEach) every time I use it?

Well, they’re pretty consistent with each other, so you’ll remember at some point. `map`, `filter`, `every`, and `some` also work in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Ya it's by default.To start using a function better if you refer some API.

I have used [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) for that.