# Using map() with a function that has two parameters

Tags: javascript, function

I know I can pass a function that looks like this to the array method `.map()`:

```
var cities = ["rome", "san francisco", "tokyo"];

var cityLen = cities.map(x => x.length);

console.log(cityLen)

// OUTPUT: [4, 13, 5]
```

I'm passing a single parameter (`x`) to the anonymous function in `map` where `x` gets progressively assigned to each of the elements of `cities`.

In the code below have been passed two parameters (`d` and `i`) to the anonymous function.

```
function numberRange (start, end) {
  return new Array(end - start).fill().map((d, i) => i + start);
}

numberRange(10, 20)

// OUTPUT [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

What are the parameters `d` and `i` inside the anonymous function and how do they get assigned? How do multiple parameters functions work with `.map()`?

Comment: second param is index while first parameter is element

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: please do a bit of research before posting.

Comment: As to where callback parameters “come from” and how they get assigned: see [Where do the parameters in a JavaScript callback function come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34624677/4642212).

Comment: @Xufox Yep, thanks.

Comment: @RaghavGarg you're right, I check out the doc but didn't find anything. Just need some rest probably. :)

Comment: @Isaac thanks, as usual, Isaac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), `Array#map` is called with three arguments:

- The current value
- The current index
- The object on which it was called

So that `map` called is called with each value in the array and its index (and the array, but it doesn't declare a parameter for it).

---

Side note: You could avoid unnecessary multiple passes through the array (basically, combine the `fill` and `map`) with `Array.from`:

```
return Array.from({length: end - start}, (d, i) => i + start);
```

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) calls its callback with the current value and its index.

Example:

```js
function numberRange (start, end) {
  return Array.from({length: end - start}, (d, i) => i + start);
}
console.log(numberRange(10, 20));
```

You could also avoid using `i` entirely by incrementing `start`:

```
return Array.from({length: end - start}, () => start++);
```

Example:

```js
function numberRange (start, end) {
  return Array.from({length: end - start}, () => start++);
}
console.log(numberRange(10, 20));
```

Comment: My bad. Didn't notice in the doc. Need some rest :)

Didn't know array.from, looks a cleaner way to accomplish the same result. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the second parameter, which is ususally the index of the actual element of `forEach`, `some`, `every`, `map`, you could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), which generates an array out of an object with a length property and has a second parameter for a mapping function.

```js
function numberRange (start, end) {
    return Array.from({ length: end - start}, (_, i) => i + start);
}

console.log(numberRange(10, 20));
```

Comment: Didn't know the Array.from. Thanks as always, Nina.