# Understanding use of closure in callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, higher-order-functions

I am trying to understand how closure is used in callback function in javascript.Can anybody explain me in detail ?

```
 function fetchData(url, callback) {
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => callback(data))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
 }
  
 //callback
 function processData(data) {
   console.log(data);
 }
  
 fetchData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", processData);
```

The callback function 'processData()' in fetchData function has access to the data variable in its outer scope,which is the result of the fetchData function.

As callbacks behave as if they are actually placed inside that
function, they are in practice closures: they can access the
containing function’s variables and parameters, and even the variables from the global scope.
`

I tried reading articles regarding same online yet I am not able to convince myself.

Comment: "*As callbacks behave as if they are actually placed inside that function, they are in practice closures: they can access the containing function’s variables and parameters, and even the variables from the global scope.*" they ***are*** closures because every single function in JS is a closure. But they don't have access to the variables in the location they are passed in.

Comment: `callback(data)` explicitly _passes_ `data` as parameter in this function call, so what does this have to do with accessing any outside scope?

Comment: The dupe on `How do Javascript closures work`, is not really the issue the OP is having, it's more how do callbacks work rather than closures.

Comment: @Keith OP seems to misunderstand both. But [Where do the parameters in a javascript callback function come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34624634) seems to be more relevant here. The closures dupe does also seem important, though, since closures don't have dynamic context as OP seems to believe and the correct mechanism is explained there.